# Comment mieux tourner « Le moi d’aujourd’hui à 30 ans et comme le toi d’aujourd’hui à 19 ans: faire l’amour, c’est comme une corvée »?

Tags: formulation-idiomatique, formulation, reformulation

Quelles seraient d’autres façons plus jolies d’écrire:

> Le moi d’aujourd’hui à 30 ans est comme le toi d’aujourd’hui à 19 ans,
> les parties de jambes en l’air se font rares: faire l’amour est comme
> une corvée. En revanche, quand j’avais ton âge, j’avais une forte
> libido, ce qui n’est pas ton cas.

Edit…tentative de reformulation.

> Tu es comme moi, tu as une faible libido, mais à ton âge,
> contrairement à toi, elle était forte

.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- Ce que tu es aujourd'hui à dix-neuf ans c'est ce que je suis  à trente, l'âge que j'ai aujourd'hui, quand les parties de jambe en l'air sont assez rares et que faire l'amour devient comme une corvée. En d'autres termes, tu n'as pas une libido bien forte, ce qui n'était pas mon cas à ton âge.
- Tu es comme moi, tu as une faible libido, mais avant l'âge étant donné les dix années que j'ai en plus, ce qui fait que c'est normal pour moi.